# Query SQL either of the values in select option

Tags: php, mysql

my sql is working fine but I would like to ask if I will only select or put a value in one of the three select option it will still show the query.

Here is my SQL

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  tblAlumni WHERE yeargrad LIKE '$year' AND department LIKE '%$dept%' AND course LIKE '$kurs' AND alum_status LIKE 2";
```

as you can see in there are three variables, the $year,$dept and $kurs.

I am trying to is if I could only select one, like only the $year but did not select $dept and $kurs and still be able to obtain the query. Please Help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite understand your question, but this is what I understand:

Use MySQL OR Condition. Also I modified your query, since you are matching year and status, use equal operation.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  tblAlumni WHERE yeargrad = '$year' OR department LIKE '%$dept%' OR course LIKE '%$kurs%' OR alum_status = 2";
```

Comment: If I select only year for example. It would show the data with the selected year. without selecting the two, the department and course. Please If you want to clarify please comment do not directly answer

Comment: Yes then you just use OR condition. The query will check if $year is present, it will just run the query for the $year.
Its not a good practice to just rely on sql syntax only, your php server side script you filter the input using if else, for the search function.

Comment: wait but the problem in this sql is that if i select the three select option with values, the first WHERE it only reads. Ex: I select yeargrad = 2002, department BSCS, and course BSIT. It shows all the yeargrad of 2002 in the table